# coldfusion scheduled task not sending emails

Tags: coldfusion

When we run a scheduled task through CFAdmin, code inside the task that is meant to send an email does not send that email. But, if we run the task url in a browser on its own, the email is sent. Anybody come across a similar issue?

Comment: Have you looked at the log? Does it show any errors?

Comment: Any chance you have cookies or other variables that your browser is supplying, but not available in the scheduled task?

Comment: Yes, there are no obvious errors

Answer (score 5):

It's difficult to say too much without seeing any actual code, but I can make some blind suggestions over and above the other responses which are all good.

- what happens if you run the task via CFSCHEDULE?
- what happens if yuo create a new task that ONLY does the email bit of the process (ie: comment-out everything else in the last, hard-coding values if need be)
- which logs have you checked for signs of errors?
- when you say you run the task via CFAdmin, do you mean "clicking the run task button", or do you mean that when it's run automatically according to its schedule?  It sounds like you mean the former, but it's not 100% clear, so I figured I'd ask.
- have you used the server monitor or FusionReactor or something to watch what's going on under the hood when the task runs?
- have you put some CFLOG entries into the script to see if it's dying at some particular point in the process, or whether there's some unexpected logic occurring that means theemailing code never gets executed, or something?
- can you list what troubleshooting steps you yourself have taken so as to minimise the number of blind suggestions people make

(sorry, this isn't really an "answer", but it's too long for just a "comment" I think).

Feed back some better info, and we can go from there...

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that when you run the task through a browser that you have authenticated to your app differently and that's why it runs in the browser - ie you have a proper session.

If you update your scheduled task to take some other action - eg write to a log file - does that work? I think the problem is not with the email but with the rest of the process.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check following steps for your schedule task

- check the log
- check the interval time
- check timeout issue of your schedule task if you assign it