# Coldfusion 8 scheduled task not running?

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks

I started a job as a web developer at a company a few months ago managing a bunch of Coldfusion applications among other things.  Apparently a scheduled task was set up many years ago, and worked fine until it stopped working under one of the previous web developers, a couple of years ago.  No one knows why it stopped working, but it is now my job to fix it.  This is my first job as a web developer, I didn't know CF when I started my job (barely knew it existed), and I only started learning about scheduled tasks this morning, so just know that I am a total newbie.

The file is a basic one- it just updates a table in the database.  If you run the URL in the browser (which is what they have been doing for the past couple of years), it runs fine, and everything is updated.  The scheduled task, which was set to run every night, has not been updating the file.  I've tried turning on the log in CF Admin, setting it to run at various times this morning, and also just telling it to run manually, and according to the log, it is executing (with no errors), but the file is not being updated.  I tried commenting out most of the file and just telling it to send a basic e-mail, with no variables or anything, but I am getting the same result.

Any ideas?  I have no idea what to try from here.  I tried looking for a solution online, but the only post I found similar to my situation is this, where people seem to be suggesting that the issue may be variables that are not available to the scheduler:

[coldfusion scheduled task not sending emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154701/coldfusion-scheduled-task-not-sending-emails)

There are no variables on my page right now though.  I tried running the task via CFSCHEDULE, per the suggestion on that page, but I got the same result as before. Some of the other suggestions (server monitor/FusionReactor/cflog) I just plain don't know how to do, so I have not tried those.

Edit: Right now, this is the only code in the page which is not commented out:

```
<cfmail 
    to="[e-mail address]"
    from="[e-mail address]"
    Subject="is it running at all?">
    Is it running?
</cfmail>
```

Edit 2: Okay, now I've got something like this before and after the code for the e-mail:

```
<cflog 
text = "before e-mail"
application = "yes"
log = "Scheduler"
type = "information">
```

I see the log messages if I actually go to the URL for the file (and the e-mail is sent as well), but not if I tell it to run the scheduled task from CF admin.  Because the e-mail sends when I open the file in the browser, I don't think it is a problem with the mail server.

Edit 3: Yes, the e-mail addresses are plain, hard-coded strings.
I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "covered" by an Application.cfm file though.  There is an Application.cfm file in the top-level of the site, but not within this particular sub-directory.  There are a number of Application scope variables, but none that are used in the file as it is now.

Edit 4: Thank you for the explanation.  As I said, total n00b when it comes to CF, so I appreciate the help.  The Application.cfm page for this application checks to see if you are logged in, and if you are not, redirects you to the log in page.  Could that be the issue?

Edit 5: YAY!  It seems like that was the issue.  Thank you thank you thank you!  Leigh, please submit that as an answer so that I can choose it.  You are my hero!

Comment: Can you post the code in your page?

Comment: If the scheduled task is definitely running (put your own [cflog](http://cfdocs.org/cflog) at the start and end of the template it calls to confirm), then we can't really help without seeing the code.

Comment: Have you confirmed the problem is not with the mail server?

Comment: Just to confirm, the real `[e-mail address]` is a plain hard coded string (not a variable)? Also, long shot but is your scheduled task inside a directory covered by an [Application.cfm/Application.cfc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d39.html) file?

Comment: Then it sounds like your script is "covered" (ie is part of the parent application.) The reason for asking is that code inside the parent Application.cfm file executes first *before* your .cfm script. Is there any code inside the Application.cfm file that aborts a request or redirects (such as permissions check)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(From the comments )

A long shot but is your scheduled task inside a directory covered by an [Application.cfm/Application.cfc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d39.html) file? The reason for asking is that the code inside the parent `Application.cfm` file executes first before your .cfm script. Is there any code inside the Application.cfm file that aborts a request or redirects (such as permissions check)?